# how can I make responsive input/button in my site?

Tags: html, css

I'm making my first website, and I want to make the Contact page like here(https://62bc5048ee1d4.site123.me),I have made it till media query's mean its ok until my screen size is not less than 1000px, when my scene is lesser than 1000px my button slices to right side and there some space on left side of my site(its not responsive but centered).Here is my HTML and CSS codes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.topper-header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: 25;
  text-decoration: underline cyan;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

#part4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.place-name {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

.row1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.row2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 490px;
  float: right;
  border-style: groove;
}

.row3 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: groove;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 490px;
  float: right;
}

#contact-input {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.row4 {
  font-weight: 10;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00ced1;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 192px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 192px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-right: -500px;
}
```

```html
<section id="part4">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="topper-header">CONTACT</h1>
    <div id="contact-input">
      <div class="first-row">
        <span class="place-name">Zagatala,Zagatala City,Azerbaijan</span>
        <input class="row1" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input class="row1" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="second-row">
        <input class="row2" type="email" placeholder="Email address">
      </div>
      <div class="third-row">
        <textarea class="row3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="row4">CONTACT US</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button has `float: right;` as part of `.row4`.
I've added a media query to let it float left.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.topper-header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: 25;
  text-decoration: underline cyan;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

#part4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.place-name {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

.row1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 30px;
  border-style: groove;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.row2 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 490px;
  float: right;
  border-style: groove;
}

.row3 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-style: groove;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 490px;
  float: right;
}

#contact-input {
  margin-left: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.row4 {
  font-weight: 10;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00ced1;
  font-size: 20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 192px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding-left: 192px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-right: -500px;
}


/* Added */

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row4 {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="part4">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="topper-header">CONTACT</h1>
    <div id="contact-input">
      <div class="first-row">
        <span class="place-name">Zagatala,Zagatala City,Azerbaijan</span>
        <input class="row1" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
        <input class="row1" type="text" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="second-row">
        <input class="row2" type="email" placeholder="Email address">
      </div>
      <div class="third-row">
        <textarea class="row3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <button class="row4">CONTACT US</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```